# InnoSetupを用いてexeファイルから　msiファイル、exeファイルを作成したい。

Tags: inno-setup

お世話になります。
私は、インストーラーなどの知識が乏しい状態ですので、
トライした事項はなく、質問しかできない状態です。
ご了承ください。

参考にできるウェブサイトなどご紹介いただけるだけでも大変ありがたいです。
業務におきまして、引継ぎが行われなかったところがあり、大変困っている状態です。
前任者はすでに退職、さらにソフトウェア開発が主の会社ではありません。

ご質問したいのは、　開発元から、実行ファイル(exe)が配布されてくるのですが、
そこから前任者は(.msi)ファイルと(.exe)ファイルを作成し配布しておりました。
前任者が作成していたexeファイルと開発元から送られているexeは名前も違い、容量も違います。

msiファイルとexeファイルの意味は調べて分かっている状態ですが、

msiファイルとexeファイルの作成方法が分からない状態です。
inno setupしか持ち合わせていないのでinno setupで教えていただきたいのですが、
他のフリーソフトで簡単に作成できるのであれば、それでも大丈夫ですので教えていただきたいです。

おそらく大変初歩的な質問なのだと思います。
ご返答いただけば幸いです。

この操作が出来れば、一通り問題なく引き継げるようになります。

Answer (score 1):

要するに

- １つの製品において実行形式ファイルは１つとは限らず `.exe` のほかに `.dll` や `.exe.config` などなど、複数のファイルが必要なことがほとんど
- ヘルプファイルとかサンプルデータファイルとかが別途必要かもしれない
- ハードウエア製品ならデバイスドライバとかも追加が必要
- 今回作成している実行形式だけでなくて `vcredist.exe` とか `.NET Framework 3.5` とか別プロジェクトを事前・事後にインストールする必要があることもある
- たいていのお客はスタートメニューやデスクトップにショートカットを追加したいだろう
- データファイルの拡張子と実行形式ファイルを関連付けしたいだろう
- そしてアプリを安全に削除するための補助情報も残しておきたいだろう

というわけでこれらの処理一式をするのがインストーラです。そして「インストーラ」 `*.msi` を作るソフトが `InnoSetup` であるとか `Visual Studio Installer Projects` です。

これらの使い方ならそこら中に解説があるわけでそちらを読んでいただくと幸い（いやオイラがここで解説してもいいですけど）

ですがその前に先ほど挙げた「インストーラで何をするの？」案件分析が必要です。それはプロジェクトによってみな違うはずなので、それはあなたが自分で整理するしかないです。そしてその機能を実現するには `InnoSetup` ならこういう操作をするとか `VSInstallerProjects` ではこういう操作をするとか、そういう話になります。前提となる案件の理解なしに解説だけ読んでもわけわからんが多いっす（オイラがそうだったので）

なので実のところ初歩的な質問などでは全くありません。

とりあえずここ jSO で「１つの製品の詳細な使いかた」の説明は困難なのでまずは自分でいろいろ記事を探して実践してみてください。「こういう機能を実現したいんだけど」みたいに質問が小さくなれば、回答してくれる人も増えるでしょう。

Comment: "jSO" という略はサイト内で広く使われているものではありませんし (SOja または jaSO は見かけます)、まだ不慣れなユーザーに対しては「スタック・オーバーフロー」と書いてあげた方がより親切かなと思いました。

Answer (score 1):

使い方で分からないことがあったら、まずは **マニュアルに頼る** (マニュアルを探す) 癖を付けることをお勧めします。

今回のケースであれば英語になりますが [Inno Setup Help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) にオンラインマニュアルがありますし、
「Inno Setup」でgoogle 検索すると [Inno Setup 日本語 デベロッパーズガイド](http://inno-setup.sidefeed.com/) というサイトもヒットします (後者は情報の鮮度が分かりませんが…)。

Answer (score 0):

InnoSetup6.0.4と仮定しますと、
InnoSetupCompilerというものが、インストールされていると思います。
それを起動して、File->Newを選択して、Wizardに沿って進めてみてください。
途中でEXEを選択する項目があるので、それをお手持ちのEXEファイルにすれば出来上がりです。